# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que Links y Social esten en la misma línea?

Tags: html

He intentado poner la etiqueta `&nbsp` y no tengo el resultado esperado.

```html
<div>
   <a href="links.html">
  <h2 class="nav">Links</h2>
   </a>  
   &nbsp;
   <a href="RedesSociales.html">
  <h2 class="nav">Social</h2>
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una etiqueta de cabecera (como **h2**) por defecto usa las siguientes propiedades css en la mayoría de los navegadores (según [esta web](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp)):

```
h2 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 0.83em;
  margin-bottom: 0.83em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

A ti, de todas esas propiedades por defecto, lo que te interesa es cambiar la siguiente propiedad para que no fuerce el salto de línea:

```
display: block;
```

Lo cual puedes hacer en línea mediante el atributo `style` dentro de la etiqueta `h2` o bien con un CSS personalizado que lo cambie, y ponerla de este modo:

```
display: inline;
```

Ejemplo con `style`:

```html
<div>
  <a href="links.html">
    <h2 style="display:inline;" class="nav">Links</h2>
  </a>
  &nbsp;
  <a href="RedesSociales.html">
    <h2 style="display:inline;" class="nav">Social</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

Ejemplo con CSS personalizado:

```css
h2 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="links.html">
    <h2 class="nav">Links</h2>
  </a>
  &nbsp;
  <a href="RedesSociales.html">
    <h2 class="nav">Social</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo!